# Error when launching jupyter notebook from anaconda navigator

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ChinmayHegde\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\ChinmayHegde\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 83, in 
from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager
File "C:\Users\ChinmayHegde\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line      17, in 
from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError
File "C:\Users\ChinmayHegde\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\__init__.py", line 33, in 
from .validator import validate, ValidationError
File "C:\Users\ChinmayHegde\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in 
from jsonschema import ValidationError
File "C:\Users\ChinmayHegde\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 12, in 
from jsonschema.exceptions import (
File "C:\Users\ChinmayHegde\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\exceptions.py", line 141, in 
@attr.s(hash=True)
AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'
```

The strange thing is this attribute error was appearing before when I used to run some python packages before. That problem was not solved and now it is getting worse. I tried to uninstall and install anaconda again. But the error is same.

Comment: Please provide some information on your environment, how you opened the notebook, etc.